Performance Error with Django Import/export
I am experiencing a performance issue with Django import-export in my production environment. When importing a spreadsheet with around 3k rows, the process ends up with only an
Internal Server Error

even while in debug mode.

However, when I run the tests in the development environment, despite the delay, it successfully completes the upload of the rows.
Am I missing any configuration, or does it really need to be faster to work correctly?
Here are my configurations:
class AtivosAssetAllocationResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        use_bulk = True
        batch_size = 1000
        model = AtivosAssetAllocation
        fields = ('id', 'grupo', 'ticker', 'siglacmd', 'ativo', 'nomeComercial', 'conservador', 'moderado', 'agressivo', 'descricao', 'aprovado',
                  'classe', 'subclasse', 'range', 'previdencia')

And for reference, here is the model:
class AtivosAssetAllocation(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    siglacmd = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    ativo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nomeComercial = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    conservador = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    moderado = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    agressivo = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    descricao = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    classe = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    subclasse = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    range = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    previdencia = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    aprovado = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.ativo

Previously, the import was done normally, but due to this error, I ended up adding the method bulk
use_bulk = True
batch_size = 1000

And in settings.py:
# Import Export
IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True
IMPORT_EXPORT_SKIP_ADMIN_LOG = True

PS: In development, the total time takes around 10 minutes to export.
Should the solution involve some Django configuration, or is it a server error?

can you share your production stack trace? (logs or turning on DEBUG), also please share your production setup (maybe there's a connection timeout or upload file limit)

@RodrigoSetti Even in debug mode, it does not provide any clues about what is happening.
I edited the question with the photo.
